# Explorer.exe opens new process even if "open folders in a single window" is chosen

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-explorer

When I try to open a folder, explorer starts in a new process even if "open folders in a single window" is chosen.

The OS is windows 7. The strange thing is that even when I try to run explorer.exe from cmd (standard permissions, no admin) the new process is spawned and there are arguments like this: `C:\Windows\explorer.exe /factory,{ceff45ee-c862-41de-aee2-a022c81eda92} -Embedding`
The parent is svchost.exe

The registry key associated with the factory {ceff45ee-c862-41de-aee2-a022c81eda92} has those values

```
(Default) REG_SZ   CLSID_SeparateSingleProcessExplorerHost
AppId     REG_SZ   {CDCBCFCA-3CDC-436f-A4E2-0E02075250C2}
```

If additional info is needed, please ask me, I'll edit my question

Comment: One instance of Explorer manages the desktop, e.g. Taskbar, so one additional process is needed to display file structure. If you get *more* than two instances, though, then Windows is ignoring that setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable Open in a new process.

1. Open `File explorer`
2. Click `View`
3. Click `Options`
4. Click `View` in the new Window
5. Find and uncheck `Automatic Launch Folder Windows in a Separate Process` ​
6. Click on OK.

[image]

Or try the register to remove the feature. Download the reg file:[Remove the Open in a new process](https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/121284d1487179536-open-new-process-context-menu-add-remove-windows-10-a-remove_open_in_new_process_context_menu.reg)